# Tune step not being small enough?

Tags: repeater

I recently got an Icom ID-51E PLUS2 and its smallest tuning step is 5kHz. I looked at [the list of repeaters in the UK](https://www.ukrepeater.net/repeaterlist1.htm?filter1=2M) and many are between 5kHz stops, such as 145.6125MHz. Is this expected? Do you just tune as close as possible to it or am I missing something regarding repeater operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is true that you have a 5 kHz tuning step, you do also have a 6.25 kHz and a 12.5 kHz tuning step. These should enable you to tune to the desired frequency.

Open the quick menu screen. Push D-Pad up/down to select the tuning step. Then press D-Pad Enter to lock in that tuning step.

Answer (score 1):

If that radio model is actually as you describe (I'm not familiar), then you cannot use it with that repeater. A 2.5 kHz frequency error is sufficient to make (5 kHz deviation) FM unusable.

If you can *program* the radio with the specified frequency, as opposed to using VFO controls, that may work. Even if it only accepts 3 digits after the MHz decimal point (so that you must enter 145.612 or 145.613) then that will be a 0.5 kHz error which I would expect to be workable if not great.

Comment: It doesn't have a keypad, so, I'm not sure how it is done yet. You can upload a CSV file with repeaters to it.